# UK standard Visa - bank statement type, proof of vacation reqest

Tags: visas, uk

I am super thankful to you guy for helping.

So, I want to go with my boyfriend to London and he will be paying for the trip mostly (9 days). We want to show them his savings account (bank statement). Is this possible or it has to be the bank statement from the account you get salary om?
I have a permanent contract and pay slips but my paycheck is not even medium amount. And so, does having an approved vacation proof is very very important?

Thank you!!!

Leona

Comment: There's also lots of relevant information at [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/92121/11491).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "having an approved vacation proof". Proof that your employer is happy for you to take the time off?

Comment: @david, my friend suggested i MUST provide them proof of my vacation request as it means i plan on coming back i guess :)

Comment: My question is, they dont want credit card account statement, is his account statement from the savings account, enough? Thanks guys :)

Comment: @Yamming2233 As explained in the linked question, it is usual to provide bank statements showing receipt of salary, as well as any savings acciunt(s) to prove financial capacity. The UK publishes guidance on documents required here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf For completeness, it would probably be helpful to know your citizenship.